# How to migrate file attachments and comments from RTC to TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, rational-team-concert, ibm-rational

We’re in the process of migration from Rational RTC to TFS 2018.  We’ve figured out to map work items between the two but having difficulty moving attachments and comments.  Does anyone have experience with this?  Perhaps using the TFS REST API ?  Any help would be appreciated.  Migrating from Rational 6.0.4 RTC/CCM to TFS 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with RTC(Rational Team Concert). One thing is clear, there are no tools for use to directly migrate artifacts and Projects from RTC to TFS. You could submit a user voice on IBM's related forums.

If you already get the work item file attachments and comments from RTC. It's able use TFS **Rest API** to update TFS work item.

[Upload an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/attachments)

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/attachments?api-version={version}&filename={string}
```

To attach a file to a work item, upload the attachment to the attachment store, then attach it to the work item.

[Add an attachment](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-an-attachment)

```
PATCH https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/299?api-version=1.0
```

The comments in TFS work item is Discussion filed, you could try to use  [Update a field](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-a-field) to update the value.

```
PATCH https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems/299?api-version=1.0
```

More  details please  refer [Update work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items) Rest API.